# How could I calculate the inverse of this bitwise formula?

Tags: python, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I'm working on practicing my algorithms and getting into some bitwise stuff which I'm not too proficient with yet.

So I have this function:

```
def fn1(a):
    return (a >> 1) ^ a
```

But I need to reverse the operation for the algorithm I'm working on. So, for example, if function `fn1(11)` returns 14, I need to create a function `fn2(14)` that returns 11. It only needs to work for positive integers.

I thought that maybe the inverse could have more than one answer, but running `fn1` thousands of times in a loop did not yield any duplicate values, so there must be only one answer for any value of `fn2`.

Comment: That's the classic formula for [Gray code](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gray_code&section=15).

Comment: Mark is correct, but assuming you didn't know the formula beforehand, you could derive the inverse relation by writing out each bit of `fn1(a)`, in terms of the bits of `a`. If particular, it isn't too hard to show that the set highest bit of `fn1(a)` is equal to that of `a`. From here, it's possible to compute all bits of `a` from the known bits of `fn1(a)` iteratively, from left to right (and possibly come up with a one-liner afterwards).

Comment: @MarkRansom recognized it as Gray code, so this [blog post](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2020/09/08/inverse-gray-code/) has your answer.

Comment: Once upon a time my dad asked me if I could find a simple inversion formula. I failed. Someone else suggested that he should use a lookup table for the inverse.

Comment: @md2perpe when I was much younger with too much time on my hands, I wrote out the bit patterns for Gray code and worked out the conversion both ways on my own. The inverse was much harder than the forward.

Comment: fn1 is actually a bijection on non-negative integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Bit sequences 11 and 00 go to *0. Bit sequences 10, 01 go to *1. So an image *1 indicates that same bit and next higher bit in *a* are flipped.
2. The leading 1-Bit in a is preceded by a 0, so remains 1.

For binary representations of *fn<sub>1</sub>(a) = b*,

*fn<sub>1</sub>(a<sub>m</sub> a<sub>m-1</sub> .... a<sub>0</sub>) = b<sub>m</sub> b<sub>m-1</sub> .... b<sub>0</sub>*

it is

*b<sub>i</sub> = a<sub>i+1</sub> ^ a<sub>i</sub>* ⇔

*a<sub>i</sub> = a<sub>i+1</sub> ^ b<sub>i</sub>* ⇔

*a<sub>i-1</sub> = a<sub>i</sub> ^ b<sub>i-1</sub>*

with this recursion and *a<sub>m</sub> = b<sub>m</sub> = 1* you get the digits a<sub>m-1</sub>, <sub>m-2</sub>, ... , a<sub>0</sub> .

### EDIT

A different observation (not yet formally proven) is that iterated application of fn<sub>1</sub> to some argument *a* will lead back to the original argument *a*.

For *a* in argument range 2<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup>...2<sup>2<sup>n+1</sup></sup>-1 the periode is *p=2<sup>n+1</sup>* , resolved *p=2<sup>floor( ld( ld (a) )+1</sup>*

With this fn<sub>1</sub><sup>-1</sup>*(a)* = fn<sub>1</sub><sup>p-1</sup>*(a)* .

As for *b=fn<sub>1</sub>(a)*, both *a* and *b* belong to the same cycle, the *p*-Formula equally applies to *b*.

Finally ***fn<sub>1</sub><sup>-1</sup>(b) = fn<sub>1</sub><sup>p-1</sup>(b)** with **p=2<sup>floor( ld( ld (b) )+1</sup>***

Here is an implementation in C++

```
typedef unsigned long long N;

N fn1(N a)
{
    return a ^ (a >> 1);
}

N floor_ld(N x);

N fn1_inv(N b)
{
    if (b<2) return b;
    N p = (N)1 << (floor_ld(floor_ld(b)) + 1);
    N y = b;
    for (int i = 1; i <= p - 1; i++)
    {
        y = fn1(y);
    }
    return y;
}

N floor_ld(N x)
{
    return x == 1 ? 0 : 1 + floor_ld(x >> 1);
}
```

### EDIT 2

A further property of fn<sub>1</sub> is, that iterations can be contracted.

Let be more general *fn<sub>k</sub>(a) := a ^(a>>k)*, then
*(fn<sub>k</sub> ∘ fn<sub>k</sub>)(a) = fn<sub>2k</sub>(a)*, by simple recalculation.

With the binary representation of *e=p-1 = ∑ α<sub>i</sub> 2 <sup>i</sup>* the common iteration becomes

*fn<sub>1</sub><sup>e</sup>(a) = ( ∏<sub>α<sub>i</sub>≠0</sub> fn<sub>1</sub><sup>{2 <sup>i</sup>}</sup> ) (a) =
( ∏<sub>α<sub>i</sub>≠0</sub> fn<sub>{2 <sup>i</sup>}</sub>) (a)*

The asymptotic complexity is O(n log n) in contrast to first attempt with digit-wise evaluation of the inverse.

```
N fn1_invC(N b)
{
    if (b < 2) return b;
    N p = (N)1 << (floor_ld(floor_ld(b)) + 1);
    N e = p - 1;
    N y = b;
    N k = 1;
    while (e != 0)
    {
        if ((e & 1) != 0)
        {
            y = y ^ (y >> k);
        }
        k <<= 1;
        e >>= 1;
    }
    return y;
}
```

Comment: This is possibly easier to understand if you mention that b_i is the xor of bits {a_m...a_i}, or in other words the parity of the prefix of a ending at bit i.

Comment: @rici no, in the forward map fn1 b_i depends only on a_{i+1} and a_i

Comment: @samg: I was talking about the reverse map. I guess I reversed a and b from your terminology, sorry.

Comment: Cannot see, your xor-invariant is correct.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly how I was thinking about it, but I'm still struggling with how I might represent it in code. In the algorithm I was solving, which is the Expanding Nebula problem from Google Foobar, I ended up just brute forcing it by generating all possible values and picking from those, but I feel like if I can implement this somehow it could be faster.  [Here's my solution for reference](https://github.com/WVAviator/google-foobar-challenges/blob/main/expanding-nebula.py). I would love some feedback on it because I figured it out without any help and I seriously doubt it's any good.

Comment: @SkyPharao In Mark Ransom's Link above is a simple implementation given ´GrayToBinary32´ https://en.m.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gray_code&section=15
I'm still looking for a recursive variant, which allows parallelization. Is there more prose to your "Nebula"-Link?

Comment: Nope just that and the three test cases labelled solution at the bottom.